# Context-specific translation of German word "an"

Tags: difference, word-choice, preposition

> Margaretha war an diesem Abend sehr stolz

I see two possibilities for translation of the above sentence.

1. On this evening, Margaretha was very proud.
2. Margaretha was very proud *of* this evening.

Would a native speaker use one of these meanings for that sentence to the exclusion of the other? If so, which one, and how would they express the other sentence differently?

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to visit the [help] to learn more about how it works. In my opinion your question is rather close to one that can be answered [by a dictionary lookup](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=stolz%20sein&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on). Please don’t be surprised if it ends up closed for not having consulted general references.

Answer (score 14):

There is no doubt whatsoever that the sentence carries the meaning 1.

This is because the phrase *to be proud of something* is translated as *auf etwas{Akk} stolz sein* thus the second sentence would instead be:

> Margaretha war *auf* diese*n* Abend sehr stolz.

(Note that the case changes from dative to accusative, too.)